# linux command to run a php file function with arguments

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec, shell-exec

I am not familiar with linux commands.But I searched my level best I could not find any solution.

Please help me Is there any command to run/execute a php file functions with arguments.

I know we can execute PHP file using below command

```
$ php -f test2.php [args]
```

But I need to execute a function inside a php file.

Or

Is there any php in-build methods to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order for php to execute the function, the only way is to write the php code calling this function. A simple php script like this one should do :

```
<?php
require('your_function_library_file.php');
yourfunction($param1, $param2);
```

That you can then execute it through the command-line you provided in the question.

Another possibility would be to write the same code directly in the command-line :

```
php -r "require('your_function_library_file.php');yourfunction($param1, $param2);"
```

Comment: I am expecting like PHPUnit.likewise in linux command or any other inbuild PHP method except PHPUnit